# How I can have a break in a variable name?

Tags: mathjax

I am using mathjax for writing equations in WordPress with Elementor. The name of variables that I use are long and I would like to break them in two lines; **not the whole equation but just the variable name**. Is there a command for that in Mathjax or Latex?

[image: a simple example two-line naming for a variable]

Comment: Don't use math font for whole words, as you can see the kerning is all messed up

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\atop` to do it:

```latex
$${\text{Fraction of} \atop \text{Persons Immune}}= .81$$
```

I've used `\text{}` to make the font be upright (as is usual for multi-character identifiers) and to preserve the spaces.